# SSHing between EC2 instances without having to provide key

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am trying to enable SSHing from one EC2 instance to another without a key. I did the following

1) Generated a key in the master instance like

```
 $ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa_master_to_slave
```

2) Added that key to the list of authorized keys of the same master instance

```
 $ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa_master_to_slave.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

3) SCPed the public key file to the slave instance.

```
 $ scp -i aws_key.pem /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa_master_to_slave.pub  ubuntu@slave:~/
```

4) Added the SCP-ed file to the list of authorized keys in the slave instance as well.

```
 $ cat id_dsa_master_to_slave.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Still when I try to SSH, I get a

```
Permission Denied (Public Key)
```

Am I missing out something?

Comment: This looks like a Server Fault question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your private key somewhere (in your home directory).
Put the following anywhere in your `.bashrc` file:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add ~/private_key.pem
```

After that, execute this once: `source ~/.bashrc`

Every time you login, `eval` and `ssh-add` will execute and you'll be ready to shh into an ec-2 server without a password.  Yes, those are NOT single-quotes, those are back-ticks.